# How to fetch a document by its ID in elasticsearch rails

Tags: elasticsearch, elasticsearch-rails

I see in the elasticsearch docs you can fetch a document by its ID. Is there any equivalent in elasticsearch rails? I'm feeding by API with  "as_indexed_json" and it's a somewhat expensive query, I'd like to return ths JSON straight out of elasticsearch in my API.

Answer (score 14):

You can fetch a particular document from a given index by id with the `get` method on `Elasticsearch::Transport::Client`.  The `get` method expects a single hash argument with keys for the index you want to fetch from and the id of the document you want to fetch.

So, all together you need 3 things:

1. A client object
2. The name of the index
3. The id of the document (i.e. your model id)

```ruby
client = YourModel.__elasticsearch__.client
document = client.get({ index: YourModel.index_name, id: id_to_find })
```

Answer (score 5):

Here how you can accomplish it.
This is from controller action and works well for me.

```
def show
  client = Elasticsearch::Client.new host:'127.0.0.1:9200', log: true
  response = client.search index: 'example', body: {query: { match: {_id: params[:id]} } }
  @example = response['hits']['hits'][0]['_source']
   respond_to do |format|
     format.html # show.html.erb
     format.js # show.js.erb
     format.json { render json: @example }
   end
  @records = Example.search(@example['name']).per(12).results
end
```